# how do I answer a question which looks to have been removed as 'ambiguous' (How can you render Eevee animations quicker was the original question)

Tags: discussion

I could not answer this question: as it had been deemed 'ambiguous', So I had to comment...(I would disagree that it's an ambiguous question, as I can answer it).
So this is in the hope of reaching the person who asked the original question.

If you're using Windows (can't speak for other OS's), and Nvidia GPUs (plural) you can DEFINITELY (DEFINITELY) render Eevee animations quicker, by running an instance of Blender per GPU. (Assuming you're not doing this already that is!)

[image: Quick screen shot of me using all 3 GPUs on one machine to render out an Eevee animation: 3 frames every 20 odd seconds rather than one]

Quick screen grab of me getting 3 frames in the same time as only one if you only render with the GUI, or 'run as administrator' the .bat file

Here's the link to what I posted on Blender Artists for the full 9 yards...
https://blenderartists.org/t/render-eevee-animations-n-times-faster/1177668

Cheers
Mark

Comment: Hi MarkS, I think it's great that your trying to help. You could post a link to this Question on the original question as a comment. However, your concerns are valid, Stackexchange Sites have a unique way of handling things, which takes a while to get accustomed to.

Comment: If you have some information you want to share (as you just did in your question), opening a new Q&A is the right way and I'm happy that you did the work. However, questions for questions and answers for answer. Please separate your post into a question (which should be the only content of the question) and add your own answer. Yes, it is not unusual to add your own answer to your own question. That way, you can (1) accept the answer (2) people can find it easily and upvote it and (3) this question will be remembered as "answered" by the system.

Comment: Hello peeps! Can't link to the original question as it's gone... Sorry, but I didn't know this 'meta' place even existed. I was only trying to pass on the answer the only way I could work out how to...

Comment: @marks in that case feel free to post a new question yourself and answer it all together, you may even gain some upvotes in the process

Answer (score 1):

Write a proper question (you can check the [help center](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help) if you're unsure how to write a good one) then add your answer.

Leave it open for a day before accepting your own answer. Who knows, maybe even someone else can come up with a better solution!

Comment: Read the previous comments: I didn't ask the question, was merely attempting to answer it when it was removed....

Comment: @MarkS I know that, but since the question got removed, _write a new one_ and self-answer. The same as Duarte Farrajota suggested in a comment, I'm just writing it as an answer.\